# Crash occurred when assigning size_t with int variable

Tags: c, migration, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I have below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(size_t *ptr)
{
    printf("Before *ptr = %d &ptr = %p\n",*ptr, &ptr);
    unsigned int len = 100;
    *ptr = len;
    printf("After *ptr = %d &ptr = %p\n",*ptr, &ptr);
}
void main()
{
    int var = 10; 
    
    printf("Before var = %d &var = %p\n",var, &var);
    func((size_t *)&var);
    printf("After var = %d &var = %p\n",var, &var);
    return;
}
```

This code is working fine in 32 bit environment.
I'm migrating the application to 64bit and in this case, code generates a core dump. It works fine in few online compiler such as code codepad.org but crashes in [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/).

I understand that in 64 bit environment size_t size would be 8byte but in case of 32 bit it is 4 byte.
So I managed to solve this by changing the below line.

```
size_t var = 10;
```

So my question is, is it wrong to assign a pointer of lower data size(for instance int) to higher data size?(For example long/size_t)

What has caused the issue in this scenario?

What are the other things I should be taking care related to pointer when migrating to 64bit environment?

Comment: *..is it wrong to..* - of course it is. You are passing a pointer to a location of a smaller size than the data you are trying to put in it. It is causing memory access violation.

Comment: _"This code is working fine in 32 bit environment."_ the code has undefined behavior in any environment afaik.

Comment: _"What are the other things I should be taking care related to pointer when migrating to 64bit environment?"_ - if you always make your pointers point at objects of the type they are defined to point at you should be fine.

Comment: In your 32 environnement `size_t` is most likely the same thing as `unsigned int`. Therefore casting an `int*` to a `size_t*` doesn't do any harm as the sizes match. But anyway, the cast in this statement `(size_t *)&var` is just plain wrong and pointless, there is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(size_t) = %zu , sizeof(int) = %zu\n", sizeof(size_t), sizeof(int));
}
```

On my system `sizeof(size_t)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`.

In your function, you write and read data from the memory which is outside the `int` variable you passed by the pointer. You access memory which was not allocated to your variable and invoke Undefined Behaviour (UB).

Comment: I want to understand, although the sizeof(int *) == sizeof(size_t *) why is it wrong to cast like ```func((size_t *)&var);``` ? where var is of type int

Comment: because the underlaying object has different size. Not the pointer, Pointer is just an address of the object. size of the pointer does not matter.

Comment: By this cast you are telling the compiler - here is an address of a variable of type `size_t`. Which is a lie, because this is an address of a variable of type `int`.

Comment: Another example. You have two boxes. In one you have an apple, in another egg. When you cast you simply change the label on the box. If you label the egg box as apple, will it change the egg to become apple or it still be the egg?

Comment: Even if they had the same size, it's still not valid. `int` is a signed type, and `size_t` is unsigned. They're not compatible.

Answer (score 3):

The following isn't correct:

```c
int var = 10; 

func( (size_t *)&var );
```

`func` will access the memory for `var` as if it's a `size_t`, but it isn't. This results in undefined behaviour.

It should be

```c
int var = 10;

size_t tmp = var;  // See note 1.
func( &tmp );
var = tmp;         // See note 2.
```

Notes:

1. This assumes the value of `var` can be represented by a `size_t`. If it can't, "the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting
   one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type."
2. This assumes the value of `tmp` can be represented by an `int`. If it can't, "either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised."